# $\int_{0}^{1}\ln^2\Gamma(x)\ln\Gamma(1-x)\ dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, logarithms, gamma-function

I came across the following integral $$\int_{0}^{1}\ln^2\Gamma(x)\ln\Gamma(1-x)\ dx$$

and I have no idea where to even start.

I know you can interchange the $x$ and $1-x$ by king's property, and that  $\int_{0}^{1}\ln^2\Gamma(x)dx$ has a nice closed form but otherwise I don't know what to do.

Comment: Numerically this is roughly 0.1775090486962202. I doubt it has a closed form but I guess we'll see.

Comment: where did you find it?

Comment: If you use the reflection formula you might get some mileage out of [the results in this paper](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/2011-139-02/S0002-9939-2010-10589-0/S0002-9939-2010-10589-0.pdf), particularly Sec. 6.

Comment: see also [here](https://carmamaths.org/resources/jon/log-gamma.pdf)